Is there a way to generate a copy of my tex file with the references made explicit?
I'd like to make a version of my tex file where every appearance of \ref and \eqref is replaced by its actual value (the explicit reference itself).
Is there a way to generate such a tex file programatically?
I need this for preparing an appendix for a journal submission (they require the appendix be separate and thus the references will be to a different file).

I would call the output number "the actual value".  I assume you want the argument to the command?  Does \usepackage{showkeys} do what you want?  (I would claim that the most common reason for your request is that your labels are not descriptive and you should change that instead, but perhaps you have a better reason.)

As it stands, your query sounds a lot ike you're asking for advice on how to shoot yourself in the foot. If that's not what you're after, please edit your query to explain your use case in greater detail.

I need it for preparing a separate appendix which would not have the correct cross referencing (since it wouldn't include the main paper).

Please add much more detail.  Now it sounds like you want the xr package, but I'm not sure.  Please show us a sample file (or two?) that has your use case.  Or could you create one pdf and use other tools to split the appendix off?
